# IOs Swift Progress View Password Evaluacion

Tags: swift, xcode

Necesitaria poder reproducir algun componente parecido a

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual tenga como una barra que indique con diferentes colores si la password esta muy debil , si es seguro   etc ,

Swift Xcode cualquier link de interes me ayuda, nisiquiera se como poder googlear esto gracias

Comment: No se si te sirva pero mira esto: [Comprobador de fuerza de contraseña de iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14544330/8933039) ,[zxcvbn: realistic password strength estimation](https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/), también
[Password Validator & Strength Evaluator](https://github.com/mattt/Navajo), 

[esto](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn-ios)

 y [esto](http://webtecker.com/2008/03/26/collection-of-password-strength-scripts/) , solo para que tomes ejemplos y puedas buscar información a partir de esto.

Comment: si fueron de utlidad muchas gracias! @J.Rodríguez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca lo he utilizado, pero tal vez esto te podría servir.

https://github.com/mattt/Navajo